# Multiple pages accessing (binding) ObservableCollection from MainPage.cs

Tags: c#, .net, xaml, microsoft-metro, windows-store-apps

I have a few Pages in my Windows Store app and in MainPage.xaml I have a GridView which bind to an ObservableCollection in MainPage.xaml.cs.

I also need to have a GridView on a different page, for example, Page2.xaml, that is bound to the ObservableCollection that is located in MainPage.xaml.cs.

Now, I thought that if I made the ObsCollection `public _static_`, I'd be able to bind to it from my Page2 page in XAML, but I was wrong. How do I do it?

MainPage:

```
<TextBlock x:Name="text" Text="{Binding MyClass}" />
```

MainPage.xaml.cs:

```
public static ObservableCollection<MyClass> ObsCollection = new ObservableCollection<MyClass>();
```

To get this to work, I have *tried*:
Page2.xaml:

```
<TextBlock x:Name="textBlock" Text="{Binding MainPage.MyClass}" />
```

But this didn't work. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be using Mvvm. Try checking out Mvvm Light, as it's quite easy to implement.

Basically, you put all of your data (described as a "Model" in the "Model-View-ViewModel" design, abbreviated Mvvm) into a "ViewModel" object. In this case, your `ObservableCollection`. Then all of your pages bind directly into your ViewModel. Mvvm creates a static "ViewModelLocator" that allows you to set the Source of all of your Bindings, and get it to work quite easily.